# I can't get the route with full slug/post

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, slug

I am trying to create a blog, when trying to bring the previous record and the next record in sight this returns the "post" but not the full path that should be / single / {slug}

CONTROLLER

```
  public function single($slug)
    {
        $post = Post::where('slug', $slug)->first();
        $previous = Post::where('id', '<', $post->id)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->where('status', 'PUBLISHED')->first();

        $next = Post::where('id', '>', $post->id)->orderBy('id')->where('status', 'PUBLISHED')->first();

        return view('web.single')->with(compact('post', 'previous', 'next'));
    }
```

---

view

```
@if (isset($previous))
                <div class="alert alert-success">
                <a href="{{ url($previous->slug) }}">
                    <div class="btn-content">
                        <div class="btn-content-title"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> Previous Post</div>
                        <p class="btn-content-subtitle">{{ $previous->title }}</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
                </div>
            @endif
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">

            @if (isset($next))
            <div class="alert alert-success">
            <a href="{{ url($next->slug) }}">
                <div class="btn-content">
                    <div class="btn-content-title">Next Post <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></div>
                    <p class="btn-content-subtitle">{{ $next->title }}</p>
                </div>
            </a>
            </div>
            @endif
```

---

Route

```
Route::get('/single/{slug}', 'Web\WorkController@single')->name('single');
```

When clicking on previous or next, the route shown by the browser is http://127.0.0.1:8000/et-autem-tempora
and should be
http://127.0.0.1:8000/single/et-autem-tempora

Answer (score 0):

You are creating your url doing this:

```
<a href="{{ url($next->slug) }}">
    ...
</a>
```

The [`url('path')`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-url) helper returns something like this: `http://{base_url}/{path}`.

Try to use [your named](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes) route instead:

```
<a href="{{ route('single', ['slug' => $next->slug]) }}">
    ...
</a>
```

I think this should also work:

```
<a href="{{ route('single', $next->slug) }}">
    ...
</a>
```